# How can I stop my pop-up from prompting for credentials after publishing to the server in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a project that is done in MVC where, on certain views which display a table from a database, a user will be able to click on a button in a given row to edit that data. When the button is clicked, a popup will appear of which the user can edit the data. What's interesting to note is that I have no issues whatsoever when I am running this locally.

However, as soon as I publish this to my webserver, the problem begins. After authenticating to the website, the expected result is that I should not be prompted for my credentials again. If I am just browsing around the different views, this result holds true. However, as soon as I click that button for a pop-up, I'm presented with an infinite loop of asking for credentials. Even if I enter in my credentials, it just asks again without any kind of error.

I shouldn't even be asked for credentials in the first place once I've already passed them upon logging into the website. Why is this happening?

I've tried playing around with the project settings and the settings on IIS, but to no avail. Currently, for the project I have these settings:

- Anonymous Authentication: Enabled Managed
- Pipeline Mode: Integrated
- SSL Enabled: False
- Windows Authentication: Enabled

On IIS, I have these settings configured:

- .Net Authorization Rules: Allow All Users Inherited
- Authentication: Annoymous and Windows are both Enabled
- Authorization Rules: Allow All Users
- SSL Settings: Accept Client certificates

For the popup itself, I'm just using a modal-dialog, as follows:

**View**

*Index.cshtml*

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ActionAway(@item.AID)">Action Event</button>
            </td>
    </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Action This Event</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    var ActionAway = function (theid) {
        var url = "/Database/Edit?id=" + theid;

        $('#myModalBodyDiv1').load(url, function () {
            $('#myModal1').modal("show");
        })
    }

</script>
```

I believe that it has something to do with how IIS is set up on the server, since it is working for me just fine locally. What could I be missing that is causing this issue? I appreciate any advice that can be given on this!

Comment: Why do you have both Anonymous and Windows authentication enabled? Choose one or the other.

Comment: Per your recommendation, I changed both to Windows authentication and disabled anonymous. Unfortunately, this did not resolve my issue. One interesting thing to note is that when I go to the website, I can select a certificate and then view the content easily. But for the button, it not only asks for a certificate, but also asks for the accompanying pin. What else can I be looking at to troubleshoot my problem?

Comment: The account set up in the IIS App pool must also have permissions in the Database.  For example if the App Pool is using a custom user account, that same account must have read/write permissions in the db. I often forget to set that, may be worth a look.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by this, BattlFrog. The application has a connection string in the web.config file for authenticating to the database, which it can use to read/write information. That aside, I can actually edit information in the database in one of my pages that does not use a popup. I have other applications on the same server that seem to work just fine; they just don't use a popup!

Comment: Is your action or controller `/Database/Edit` modified with an AuthorizeAttribute?
Can you validate that once you login you are you and not anonymous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ton of troubleshooting, I was able to find the solution. The issue lies in my  section. Specifically, this line:

```
var url = "/Database/Edit?id=" + theid;
```

This works just fine locally, but once I published it to the server, I had to change it to the following:

```
var url = "//server/application/Database/Edit?id=" + theid;
```

I'm sure there is an easier way to do this, but this was the solution I found for now. Thanks everyone for your help!